# Mathematic font typesets differently in savebox environment

Tags: beamer, math-mode, fonts, boxes

When I typeset the same equations using beamer inside a savebox environment, and inside the main document, the font used for the math equations comes out differently.

Here is a MWE showing the difference.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand{\delsq}[2]{
  \frac{\partial^2 {#1}}{\partial {#2}^2}
}
\newcommand{\deldel}[2]{
  \frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}
}

\newcommand{\waveEqOneD}{\delsq{u}{t} = c^2\delsq{u}{x}}

\newsavebox{\waveEquationTest}
\savebox{\waveEquationTest}{
  $\begin{array}{ll}
    u(0,t)=0 & u(L,t)=0\\
    u(x,0)=f(x) & \deldel{u}{t}(x,0)=g(x)\\
  \end{array}$
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Begin document           %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame}{Boundary conditions}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \usebox{\waveEquationTest}
  $\begin{array}{ll}
    u(0,t)=0 & u(L,t)=0\\
    u(x,0)=f(x) & \deldel{u}{t}(x,0)=g(x)\\
  \end{array}$
\end{frame}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

The same code is used inside and outside the savebox environment, but the font used to render the code is different.

My question is why do these typeset differently?

Secondly, I actually prefer the look of the italicized font *inside* the savebox environment. How can I make that the default mathematics font throughout the entire presentation?

Answer (score 6):

The `beamer` class redefines some of the fonts at `\begin{document}`.  This is so it can support font packages you load in the preamble after the `\documentclass`.  If you move the `\savebox` from the preamble into the document, it will see that `beamer` changed the math letters to sans-serif italic and use the same fonts as other math.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand{\delsq}[2]{
  \frac{\partial^2 {#1}}{\partial {#2}^2}
}
\newcommand{\deldel}[2]{
  \frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}
}

\newcommand{\waveEqOneD}{\delsq{u}{t} = c^2\delsq{u}{x}}

\newsavebox{\waveEquationTest}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Begin document           %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\savebox{\waveEquationTest}{
  $\begin{array}{ll}
    u(0,t)=0 & u(L,t)=0\\
    u(x,0)=f(x) & \deldel{u}{t}(x,0)=g(x)\\
  \end{array}$
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame}{Boundary conditions}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \usebox{\waveEquationTest}
  $\begin{array}{ll}
    u(0,t)=0 & u(L,t)=0\\
    u(x,0)=f(x) & \deldel{u}{t}(x,0)=g(x)\\
  \end{array}$
\end{frame}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

The font that will be used inside the `\savebox`, if you define it in the preamble, is the default serif font (Computer Modern Roman Italic).  I would recommend that you set your fonts in `beamer` by adding the line

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
```

and compiling in LuaLaTeX.  If `beamer` sees `unicode-math`, it turns its redefinition of the math fonts off and uses the math font you select.  If you’re writing a `beamer` presentation, your publisher is not forcing you to use PDFTeX and legacy fonts.  You can then set any OpenType fonts of your choice, such as `\usepackage{newcomputermodern}` for a slightly-darker clone of the default TeX font.

A PDFTeX-compatible way to do it, though, is to add

```
\usefonttheme{serif}
```

Comment: Thank you, for the well written and comprehensive answer.